# iPhone Interface Orientation- What is wrong with this?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, interface, xcode4, orientation

I am currently creating an iPhone app using Xcode 4.0.2, I want the app to switch views when the user turns their phone. For example: If a user turns their iPhone on it's side, the iPhone would change to a pre-made landscape view. I have created the code for it, but when I run it in iOS Simulator and rotate the device nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

Header File:

```
#import "FlipsideViewController.h"

@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <FlipsideViewControllerDelegate> {
IBOutlet UIView *portraitView;
IBOutlet UIView *landscapeView;

}
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIView *portraitView;

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIView *landscapeView;

@end
```

Implementation File (.m):

```
#import "MainViewController.h"
#define deg2rad (3.1415926/180.0)

@implementation MainViewController
@synthesize portraitView;
@synthesize landscapeView;

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
// Return YES for supported orientations.
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}

-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {

if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
    self.view=landscapeView;
    self.view.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(deg2rad*(90));
    self.view.bounds=CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 480.0, 320.0);
} else if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
    self.view=landscapeView;
    self.view.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(deg2rad*(-90));
    self.view.bounds=CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 480.0, 320.0);
} else {
    self.view=portraitView;
    self.view.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(deg2rad*(0));
    self.view.bounds=CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 300.0, 460.0);
}

[super willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration];

}

@end
```

I have taken out some things that are not necessary, so the .m file may look a little bit bare. I have linked the IBOutlets landscapeView and portraitView to 2 different views within one .xib file called MainViewController.xib

When I build it, there are no errors, warnings, or signals.

Is there an easier way to do this or am I just doing it wrong? Could somebody help?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to fix your shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation for one.  The return value will always match up with the first, it should look more like

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
// Return YES for supported orientations.
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
        || (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
        ||(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}
```

Comment: That's one of the annoying things about xcode, it doesn't warn about unreachable or dead code,  Your second 2 return statements were unreachable, because the function would exit upon hitting the first